# Getting an error while connecting Sql server using cmd. Please helpp

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm `Completely new to sql server` database and I don't where to start my server. After googleing I started server selecting an option from `Sql server configuration manager`. Now as I type `sqlcmd` into command prompt. It gives me the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL SErver Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider :
Ciould not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
```

See Screenshot at http://postimg.org/image/aawe3kvx3/

What to do?

Comment: are you want how to install sql server?

Comment: No.. I installed alrealdy .. `Sql server 2014` but asking when i type `sqlcmd` using `cmd` it says that error see above i posted a screenshot..

Comment: open task manager go on services  then click service button find sqlservice and then start this service

Comment: @Kishan: I guess you're not good familiar with `Sql server`.. thanks anyway..

Comment: accept it if i am write

Comment: sorry reading mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx

so try for example:

```
 sqlcmd -S .\SqlExpress
```

To be sure that your service is running run following command:

```
  net start MSSQLSERVER
```

Although if it is default instance on the same computer simple `sqlcmd` should work. 
If you run just `sqlcmd` without any parametrs it connects to localhost and default instance.
It seems that you installed a named instance of SQL Server or the instance of SQL Server is on another computer.

Try first to connect using SQL Server Management Studio - that would be easier to figure out.

Also check your configuration.

[image: StartMenu]

[image: SQLConfManager]

[image: YouSeeInstanceNameHere]

The instance name of your SQL Server you can figure out in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

See this for few useful steps to take after SQL Server installation.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2014/post-installation-steps/

If you install SQL Express it is usually better to instal `Express with Tools (SQLEXPRWT)` version. http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx 
That version includes SQL Management Studio.

Comment: I guess i need first to download `sql server management studio`.. :( ..becuase after using `computer name` still its not working......look into [SCREENSHOT](http://postimg.org/image/jwcmmiowz/)

Comment: Added couple of other tips - it is usually better yo install Express with Tools, but if you do not need it for development than it is not necessary.

Comment: When i type `net start MSSQLSERVER` it says "The service name is invalid" .. what that means?

Comment: Did you try `sqlcmd -S .\SQLExpress` ? Or perhaps you have installed LocalDB edition?

Comment: Yes i tried `sqlcmd -S .\SQLExpress` and it says this-> [SCREENSHOT](http://postimg.org/image/623xluj2p/)

Comment: It means that you have succesfully connected.

Comment: okay.. now here i could create database into that `cmd prompt`?

Comment: Don't bother with the command prompt. Download the tools as suggested.